# What is the difference between test1 = np.random.randint((11, 20, 50)) and test1 = np.random.randint(11, 20, 50)

Tags: python, numpy, random

While the 1st one gives me a solution

```
test1 = np.random.randint((11, 20, 50))
>>> random array with order (1,3)
```

ex- array([ 1,  3, 43])

While the second one gives

```
test1 = np.random.randint(11, 20, 50)
>>> 50 random values b/w 11 to 20 in an array
```

ex- array([17, 16, 14, 16, 18, 19, 19, 13, 13, 13, 14, 12, 16, 12, 16, 17, 19,
           19, 12, 14, 17, 11, 19, 14, 16, 13, 17, 12, 12, 19, 14, 18, 15, 17,
           11, 12, 15, 16, 13, 16, 14, 19, 12, 18, 12, 15, 13, 14, 16, 12])

So my question is why does it behave differently with only () parentheses

Comment: The first sets `low` to `(11,20,50)`, and generates one random value for each element.  The second sets `low` to 11, `high` to 20, and `size` to 50.  Read the docs carefully.  In Python, the use of `()` in function arguments can make a big difference.  There are some `numpy` cases where `()` are optional, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @hpaulj first of all, thank you for reply. I got the second case but I'm still confused with the first one

Comment: Correction, in the first case only one argument is provided.  In that case it actually sets the `high` parameter.  `low` is still 0.  It's a way of generating a set of values over different ranges.  Look at the example described as "Generate a 1 x 3 array with 3 different upper bounds"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two cases are the same as:

```
In [211]: np.random.randint(low=0,high=(11, 20, 50),size=3)                                    
Out[211]: array([ 2, 17,  7])
In [212]: np.random.randint(low=11, high=20, size=50).shape                                    
Out[212]: (50,)
```

One returns one value for each of the ranges defined by the `low` and `high` tuples, the other returns multiple values evaluated on one common range.

The second is the most common usage.  The first is a convenience that someone though would be useful for some people.  It might not be widely used or well thought out.  I wouldn't put a lot of effort into understanding it, unless I really had a need for something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @hpaulj . Ik the second is the most common usage, but when coding by mistake I entered the 1st one and wondered how the result has changed and wanted to know how it ranges out of curiosity.